# How do I serialize multiple objects with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to serialize a list of objects I have in a particular format.  The XML structure will be:

```
<doc>
    <data>
       <item>
          ... object properties go here ...
       </item>
    </data>
</doc>
```

So far I have the whole structure of an  element working properly, but this code below will create it as an XML document itself, I need to be able to loop through my array and add them all to the structure described above.

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Concern.class);

JAXBElement<Concern> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement(new QName("item"), Concern.class, concerns.get(0));
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
m.marshal(new JAXBElement(new QName("item"), Concern.class, concerns.get(0)), sw);
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need classes representing the "doc" and "data" tags (say Doc and Data).  then you create a Doc instance, add a Data instance to it, and lastly add all your Concern instances to the Data instance.  then marshal the Doc instance.

Comment: @jtahlborn - You can use `@XmlEleentWrapper(name="data")` to avoid the need of having a class to represent the data tag: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9023238/383861

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Doc {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="data")
    @XmlElement(name="item")
    private List<Concern> concerns;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html